# Visualine Node Importance in Graph Convolution

Tags: convolution, attention

I am quite new to the concept of attention. I am working with graph data and running graph convolution on it to learn node level embedding first. Then an attention layer to aggregate the nodes to learn a graph level embedding. Here is the setup:

graph->Conv1(Filter size 128)->Conv2-(Filter size 64>Conv3(Filter size 32) -> Attention -> Some other layers

After three convolution pass i get a matrix of size number_of_nodes_in_the_graph X 32 (embedding length). After the attention layer i get a flat vector representation of the graph with length 32. Here is the forward function of the attention module:

```
def forward(self, embedding):
    """
    Making a forward propagation pass to create a graph level representation.
    :param embedding: Result of the GCN.
    :return representation: A graph level representation vector. 
    """
    global_context = torch.mean(torch.matmul(embedding, self.weight_matrix), dim=0)
    # print("Gloabal Context:", global_context.shape)

    transformed_global = torch.tanh(global_context)
    # print("transformed_global Context:", transformed_global.shape)

    sigmoid_scores = torch.sigmoid(torch.mm(embedding,transformed_global.view(-1,1)))
    # print("sigmoid_scores Context:", sigmoid_scores)

    representation = torch.mm(torch.t(embedding),sigmoid_scores)
    return representation, transformed_global
```

Now i would like to see which graph nodes were important for the final graph embedding. I am using pytorch for this. I cannot seem to figure out how to map the attention output to input. I would greatly appreciate any help! I am using this repo: https://github.com/benedekrozemberczki/SimGNN

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell of the code, `sigmoid_scores` would be the attention weights you're looking for.